# AWS Lake Formation, Can we add LF tag to column in nested JSON?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, aws-lake-formation

Ex. 1 table with 10 columns, out of which 1 column is structarray:<struct<array<id,name,address>>>
With multiple levels of structs and arrays inside them. Can we hide "Name" column by adding LF tag to it? Tags are already defined and assigned to required IAM roles. Just want to hide 1 of the nested value from the whole struct or array column from other users.
I did some research and didnt get specific input on docs, any pointers would really approciated.
Thanks